# VBA Outlook Mailitem - not displaying all items

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, populate, mailitem

The below code does not pick up all of my emails in the Inbox.

The first item in my list box is an email from yesterday and the last 4/22/2014 - although my mailbox contains A LOT more than that.

```
Sub CheckEmail()

On Error Resume Next

Dim outApp As Outlook.Application
Dim outNs As Outlook.Namespace
Dim outFldr As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim outEmail As Outlook.MailItem

Dim p As Integer
p = 0

Set outApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set outNs = outApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set outFldr = outNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

Dim searcht As String

'find search string

' do search

        For Each outEmail In outFldr.Items

            With fmShowsInboxEmails.ListBox1
                .AddItem outEmail.EntryID
                .List(p, 1) = outEmail.ReceivedTime
                .List(p, 2) = outEmail.Subject
                .List(p, 3) = outEmail.SenderEmailAddress
                .List(p, 4) = outEmail.Attachments.Count
            End With

            p = p + 1

        Next outEmail

On Error GoTo 0

Set outApp = Nothing
Set outNs = Nothing
Set outFldr = Nothing
Set outEmail = Nothing

fmShowsInboxEmails.Show

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you notice anything specific about the emails that it doesn't list?

Comment: Nothing I can notice! Some today and then it seems to list EVERY email up until the last then stops.

Comment: a list box can only hold so many items, 65534.  How many are being returned?

Comment: I set up my work exchange email at home around the time of the first email thats listed.

Comment: not that many!!! 100 max - and its the first that are missing!

Comment: So it appears that it is working just that not all your emails have copied across. Try opening the first few emails, to view them fully.

Comment: I have checked the item count at work and at home (both having the same exchange email address account) and the count differs?

Comment: Yes i have!!! I will try again!

Comment: Obvious debugging would be to get rid of your `On Error Resume Next` statement. There is almost never a good reason to use that, especially when you are trying to debug peculiarities in the output of your functions.

Comment: @David Zemens I changed variable to a variant and it picked up the email??? The mailitem object didn't pick it up. I checked the item type of the email in the for loop and it WAS a mailitem..... Any idea's why

Comment: no idea... if you leave it declared `As Outlook.MailItem`, I assume it raises an error -- what error message?

Comment: **type mismatch** on the **Next outEmail**

Comment: @DavidZemens Although it does pick up SOME email, not all

Comment: is it possible that the collection is changing while the macro is running? Not sure that would raise the error you describe (I'd expect more of a list index out of range...)  If new emails are arriving *while* the macro is running, it's possible that some would maybe not get picked up by the macro, that's just a guess, though (and not a very good one, I think because that doesn't seem to explain why it works if you change to `Variant`).

Answer (score 1):

"type mismatch on the Next outEmail"

Items in the Inbox need not be mailitems.

Once you have Dim outEmail As Variant, test that outEmail is a mailitem before adding to the listbox.

Answer (score 1):

I think Outlook only counts items stored locally in the offline folder - so the messages stored on the server will not be a part of outFldr.Items