# VBA: not all Outlook Emails show up

Tags: vba, outlook, directory

I wrote a small piece of code, that checks an additional inbox (besides my main-adress in Outlook) for E-Mails.

The problem shows up, when using the code on a pc, where only the additional inbox is added to outlook (as the main inbox). Obviously, the code can't retrieve all Emails, only the older ones. That's awkward, because the path to the subfolders and even the emails seem to be found, but not the newer ones. I can see them in Outlook with no problem.

Does anyone have an idea, why this is happening? As I told, the same code works with no problem on a PC with an Outlook-Installation, with another main-inbox and the inbox that needs to be checked as additional one.

That's the code I use to access Outlook and the Emails:

```
Dim objFolder As Outlook.Folder
Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")    
Set objFolder = objOL.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders.Item("test@test.de").Folders.Item("Posteingang").Folders.Item("Subfolder-Name").Folders.Item("Subfolder-Name-2")
With objFolder.Items(1)
...
```

Comment: This question is similar to mine, but wasn't resolved there either: [VBA Outlook Mailitem - not displaying all items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003325/vba-outlook-mailitem-not-displaying-all-items)

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue: in my case the emails were in microsoft exchange but were not downloaded to the local outlook.

If you can refresh the outlook it should resolve the problem

Answer (score 1):

I have found that changing the cache mode setting in Outlook helps with this problem of emails being in Microsoft Exchange not being accessed thru Excel VBA, especially Step (3) below.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/turn-on-cached-exchange-mode-7885af08-9a60-4ec3-850a-e221c1ed0c1c

1. Click File > Account Settings > Account Settings.
2. Click the Exchange or Microsoft 365, and then click Change.
3. Under Offline Settings, check Use Cached Exchange Mode.
   (If you're a Microsoft 365 subscriber with semi-annual updates, under Offline Settings, check Use Cached Exchange Mode to download email to an Outlook data file.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you always retrieving the first item in the Items collection? Would you not want to loop through the items?

```
set objItems = objFolder.Items
objItems.Sort "[ReceivedTime]"
'now objItems is sorted
```

Comment: You are right. Normally I loop. This Code is just to demonstrate the problem, since this first eMail is not the newest one, although there is a newer one in Outlook.

Comment: You should not expect the first item to be the oldest or the newest item. Nothing is guaranteed until you actually sort the Items collection. See the updated answer above

Comment: This doesn't help, sorry. The eMails are not sorted in the wrong order, they are simply not there (at least for VBA). If I loop through all eMails, the newest ones _never_ appear, neither at the beginning nor at the end of the list.

Comment: Is Outlook running at the time your code is executed? Are you sure you end up in the right folder?

Comment: Yes, Outlook is running. Yes I'm in the right folder. Whenever I delete the email, that I selected with VBA and run the tool again, this mail is gone (which shows me that I'm definitely in the right folder). As soon as I delete and reconfigure the mail-account in Outlook, all recent emails show up. But new incoming mails won't be recognized by VBA. I assume it's a problem with Outlook.

Comment: I now reduced the code to 5 lines and the problem is still the same. I'm now sure it has something to do with the Setup of Outlook. Any ideas? @Dmitry Streblechenko

Comment: Does the script work in OutlookSpy (click Script button, paste the script, click Run)? Replace the CreateObject line with the "Set objOL = Application" to use the intrinsic Application object. Is your code running in a standalone exe or an Outlook VBA script?

Comment: I forgot to tell that I use this Script in Excel-VBA, sorry for that. Nevertheless, the Code (with some adaptations to Outlook-VBA) does the same error in OutlookSpy. @Dmitry Streblechenko